# Can't copy outlook directory to excel,word etc

Tags: html, directory, outlook, copy, office365

Essentially I want to copy my outlook directory to word or excel. It is an organisations directory but containing the emails and names of peers however I am lost as to how to move the data to outside of the outlooks browser. 
You cannot select the text by dragging the mouse over it and I have tried some python which also ended up not working.

[image: Screenshot of the directory]

any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is only for programming related questions (or about tools primarily used for programming). You could try to ask it at [su].

Comment: @Ivar can people still comment on my post or have you blocked it? quite new to stack overflow so im not sure how everything works.

Comment: People can add answers to your questions as long as the question is not closed. But off-topic questions are usually closed quitte fast. Comments on the other hand (like this one) can (almost) always be added to posts, even if they are closed. But those are not for answering.

Comment: Did you flag my post? Just curious as to why. I'm open to a solution that would require python or any other language for that matter?

Comment: I did vote-to-close'd your question for the exact reason mentioned in my first comment. But as mentioned, I think your question will be fine on [su] so you could just ask it there and delete this one. If you have tried something in Python, but got stuck at some point, then your question would be fine here, but questions simply asking to write the code for you are also usually closed as off-topic (as too broad). You can find more information about what you can ask about here [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).